# noUISlider - 2 handles, swap minimum and maximum

Tags: nouislider

What I want to do is use the 2 sliders I currently have and when I get the most right one, I can drag it past the left one. So they turn around.
I have thought of 2 possible ways to do this, namely by either swapping some classes around (this didn't seem to work) or by changing what element is being dragged.

Current code:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('test5');
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [20, 80],
 connect: true,
 step: 1,
 range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100
 },
 format: wNumb({
  decimals: 0
 })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/extras/noUiSlider/nouislider.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/extras/noUiSlider/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div style="padding:20px"></div>
<div id="test5"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Handles passing each other is not a feature in this library.

Comment: I realise that, I was wondering if there is a way to do this anyway with this library, since I use materialize and this has built in support for it.